# Access Bind9 DNS in Virtualbox on Host

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, virtualbox

I've set up a Ubuntu 10.04 Virtual Box with a Bind9 DNS server. The Box has a NAT Network connection for internet access and a host-only adapter for static ip connections from the host (OSX Lion). Thats the only way i managed to get internet and static ip inside the box, guess there is a better one ...
The DNS works fine from inside the virtualbox, but not from the host. The http and ftp on the guest system is accessible via both addresses, so connection between host and guest are fine i guess. I tried to add both IP's as name servers.
I'm completely new to Bind9 and DNS configuration. Anybody has a hint for me whats wrong? Or how i have to configure the DNS server?

Comment: Could you show the BIND config you have? At a guess I'd say the IP the outside machine comes at has not been added to the range of addresses that can query the BIND. If you don't know much about DNS, I'd suggest getting the O'Reilly book on DNS & BIND - it gives a great intro to how DNS works, then great info on how BIND works, and how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the DNS only listen to localhost. Check in the VM :

```
# netstat -naptu | grep 53
```

It should show you whether port 53 only listen to localhost (127.0.0.1). If this is the case then you have to check your configuration on allow-query.

Reference on allow-query : http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/queries.html

Answer (score 0):

Your VirtualBox network configuration sounds weird. The best approach is to configure bridged networking, which puts the VM directly on the LAN. The static IP should just be configured inside the VM.

DNS operates on port 53, mostly UDP but TCP as well. Test basic connectivity with `ping` and then `telnet` on port 53.